# What does "you're every song" mean?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

What does "you're every song" mean? 
http://www.metrolyrics.com/everything-lyrics-michael-buble.html

Answer (score 1):

The song describes the woman as everything that is good in the world. Songs are good. In fact as a singer songs are really good because that is his job. So all the songs he sings are for her. And most songs are about love in which case they are probably about her too. And she is as important to him as all the songs. Something like that maybe.